# Unmanned laser need to be UL Approved

Tags: ul

I'm going to build a mobile unmanned imitation rock that has a green laser that is going to come on automatically every 15 minutes after dark and it will sweep 90 degrees.

Will I need to have it approved by any entity before selling it to the public/local golf courses?

Does this have to be UL approved?

Comment: If you are in the USA, then the FAA will not be pleased. https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/lasers/laser_education/

Comment: Restrictions and certifications will make your project absurdly difficult and expensive. You can get what you want, with restrictions, but I hope you have deep pockets...

Answer (score 1):

The AC power supply must meet safety standards.

But your question is about the laser.

The FDA says...

```
TITLE 21--FOOD AND DRUGS
CHAPTER I--FOOD AND DRUG ADMINISTRATION
DEPARTMENT OF HEALTH AND HUMAN SERVICES
SUBCHAPTER J--RADIOLOGICAL HEALTH
PART 1040 -- PERFORMANCE STANDARDS FOR LIGHT-EMITTING PRODUCTS
```

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfCFR/CFRSearch.cfm?fr=1040.10

Also [Ref](https://htm.fandom.com/wiki/21_CFR_1040.10_(Laser_products))

- International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) Standard 60825-1, Ed. 1.2: 2001-08
- ANSI Z136 standards are available from the Laser Institute of America (www.laserinstitute.org)

The American National Standards Institute (ANSI) publishes standards for the Safe Use of Lasers2:

Z136.1 American National Standard for the Safe Use of Lasers: 2000
Z136.5 American National Standard for the Safe Use of Lasers in Educational Institutions: 2000
Z136.6 American National Standard for the Safe Use of Lasers Outdoors: 2000

People who operate Class IIIb lasers should be familiar with these standards to ensure the laser is used safely.